# Missing a cast when using Math.Ceiling

Tags: c#, casting

I've just started working with C# and Visual Studio for college, and I'm struggling with using the `Math.Ceiling` in order to have a float value round up to the next integer before it's outputted.

Visual Studio says I'm missing a cast, but I don't really know where. It's probably really simple, but being new I don't really know where to start.
The final line shown is where I've got a problem.

I could just do with someone telling me where I'm going wrong here.

I tried using a `float.Parse` around the `Math.Ceiling` but that doesn't work apparently

```cs
const float FencePanelWidth = 1.5f;
float GWidth;
float GLength;
float GPerimetre;
float FencePanelsNeed;
float FencePanelsNeed2;

Console.Write("");
Console.Write("");
GWidth = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("");
GLength = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
GPerimetre = (GLength * 2) + GWidth;
FencePanelsNeed = GPerimetre / FencePanelWidth;

FencePanelsNeed2 = Math.Ceiling(FencePanelsNeed);
```

If `FencePanelsNeed` was say 7.24, I'd want `FencePanelsNeed2` to be 8.

Comment: cast it to an int, if lower then the original it has rounded down. just add 1, else take the int value

Comment: Like you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.8#code-try-1), there are only two overloads for `Ceiling`, with `decimal` and `double`. So you need to cast the `double` result back to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling) method has only two overloads:

1. `public static decimal Ceiling (decimal d);` - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Ceiling_System_Decimal_).
2. `public static double Ceiling (double a);` - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Ceiling_System_Double_).

In your case, it uses the second overload (because the passed `float` value gets casted to `double`, and therefore, returns a `double`.

What you should do is cast the returned value to `int` or `float`:

```
FencePanelsNeed2 = (int)Math.Ceiling(FencePanelsNeed); // Or:
//FencePanelsNeed2 = (float)Math.Ceiling(FencePanelsNeed);
```

If you cast it to an `int`, you might also declare your `FencePanelsNeed2` as int instead of float.

Note that if `FencePanelsNeed2` were declared as `double`, you wouldn't get that error in the first place because no cast would be needed. So, it only comes down to which type you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to an int and add 1, will always work

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    const float FencePanelWidth = 7.24f;
    public static void Main()
    {
        var FencePanelsNeed2 = (int)FencePanelWidth < FencePanelWidth ? (int)FencePanelWidth + 1 : (int)FencePanelWidth;
        Console.WriteLine(FencePanelsNeed2);
    }
}
```

Try it [for yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I5PeuH).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I did, look at line  (int)FencePanelWidth<FencePanelWidth

Comment: You are right. That line wasn't very readable because of the missing spaces. I fixed it for you.